# VestCP (Nginx+php-fpm) + Wordpress + Elementor = 502

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Есть интернет магазин на WP + Woocommerce (20 000 + товаров) 
Кто может подкинуть хорошею статью про ускорение . Ужасно фризит , ссылка открывается за 10-15 сек.

Так же имеется проблема с Elementor (использую для главной и ещё пару страниц (контакты и.т.д)) 
При попытке редактировать в Elementor получаю 502 .

```
03390 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

Иногда бывает и такое

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet.
```

DNS прописаны через Cloudflare (мб в этом проблема).

Answer (score 0):

Autooptimize + WPSuperCache + Cloudflare + DB Optimize
Настройки php-fpm

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 256
pm.max_requests = 6000
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s
pm.status_path = /status
pm.start_servers = 8
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
```

P.S на сервере 2Гб. ОЗУ
Этого было мало ! Создал свап на 4Гб.